# Validate node request body param type

Tags: javascript

I am working on an API route controller where I have to ensure that the `count` param sent along in the request body is a number. Checking `typeof count` always returns `string`.

How do I correctly validate that `count` is a number?

```
// sample request 1 -  { count: '90' }

(req, res, next) => {
  const { count } = req.body;

  console.log(typeof count);
  // string
}
```

Comment: Maybe use Number.isNaN?

Comment: what if you log it from the body? `console.log(typeof req.body.count)`

Comment: Why NaN? Simple solution is to check typeof. More complex is to get some lib to do that.

Comment: You should check this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN thats overkill to check a simple value

Comment: @mast3rd3mon he said paramsn in request body.So,definately not simple one

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN how isnt it simple? why does he need a whole new library/package to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this validation issue by parsing the `qty` param as JSON then checking the type of the parsed param:

```
(req, res, next) => {
  const { count } = req.body;            //  count = '1'  ||  'one'
  parsedCount = JSON.parse(count);      //   count =  1   ||  SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0
  console.log(typeof parsedCount)        //   'number'
  // 'number'
}
```

However, this terminates the app whenever `qty` is not parsable. To fix that, I used an helper function which returns the parsed `qty`, which can then be validated with typeof:

```
const jsonParse = arg => {
  let parsed
  try {
    parsed = JSON.parse(arg);
  } catch (err) {
      // logger(err);
  }
  return parsed;
}
(req, res, next) => {
  const { count } = req.body;            //  count = '1'  ||  'one'

  if (typeof jsonParse(qty) === 'number'){
    next();
  } else {
    // send error message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple check is to use typeof

```
const request = {val:4};
console.log(typeof request.val === 'number'); // true
```

Problems will come here:

```
console.log(typeof Number.NaN === 'number'); // true
console.log(typeof new Number(5) === 'number'); // false
```

For more complex solution you can try this.

```js
function isNumberStrict(num) {
    const check = num && typeof num.valueOf === 'function' ? num.valueOf() : num;
    return typeof check === 'number' && Number.isFinite(check);
}


console.log(isNumberStrict('4')); // false
console.log(isNumberStrict(Number.NaN)); // false
console.log(isNumberStrict(5)); // true
console.log(isNumberStrict(new Number(4))); //true
```

If you need (want) you can get this from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-number-strict)

```
npm i is-number-strict
```